# Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'flutter_project'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I used android studio to import flutter project.I fixed some bugs but the `run` button is still disabled as in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS5ns.png)

when i clicked the `Make Project` button , i get this error message

> Task 'assemble' not found in root project '**flutter_project_name**'.

i know this issue is solved her in android projects but,

---

How to solve it in flutter project ?

---

and Does this error is the reason why `run` button is disabled?

---

### edit:

the exception is not related to the button disable issue. 
the `run` button problem is solved by creating flutter run configuration

- click on `Edit Configuration`
- click the `plus` icon.
- select `flutter`

**note :** the exception does not prevent the project from running.

Comment: Does running `flutter run` work in the command line?

Comment: indeed i am beginner i don't know how to check if it work or not?

Comment: i discovered the terminal , i wrote 'run' command but the terminal displayed ' _'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command_,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to type `flutter run` not just run on its own

Comment: thank you for helping but i solved it and i put the answer as an edit to the post

Comment: It seems that you need to have guide for set-up, check [this documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio) to properly configure your project. Also, could you share in the answer section the solution of your issue?

Answer (score 2):

the problem for me was that i didn't had settings.gradle under root project
so, add that file under root project flutter_project_name
and add this line in it

```
include ':app'
```

hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Flutter project should set a run config by default, and importing a Flutter project should be able to read the run config from the project as well. It's likely that the Flutter project that you've imported doesn't have a run config set up.

In this case, you can simply click `Add configuration...` from the menu bar.

[image: add config]

Click `Add New Configuration`, select `Flutter`, and set the Flutter project's main.dart on `Dart entry point`.

[image: set run config]